# Can I use Unicode as Java variables?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, javac

Is it possible to use Unicode as variable names in Java? For example:

```
public static double δ = 1.001;
```

Whenever I do something like this in Java (from [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)), I get an error:

> 'java: expected'

or

> java: illegal start of expression

Is there a way to make it so that δ can be used as a variable in Java?

If not, are there any alternatives I could use?

Comment: What error are you seeing? Is it a true Java error, or is it an IDE error?

Comment: I get an error like 'java:<identifier> expected' or "java: illegal start of expression"

Comment: [It works when I try it.](http://ideone.com/14SuqU) Maybe you have other bugs, or maybe your IDE can't handle it. What tool are you using that's giving you the error message?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA. Latest version.

http://gyazo.com/2b85303eb26dc94853f7c4ea53a5cc27

Comment: Possible though this is, I think this is a bad idea. Why not use `sigma` for the variable name? How could anyone type this variable name (`δ`) without an exotic key sequence or copy paste?

Comment: 'How could anyone type this variable name (δ)' ... Americans are not the only programmers.  US keyboards are [not the only keyboards](https://www.greece.com/info/language/greek_keyboard/).

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), it is possible:

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of **Unicode letters** and digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the underscore character "*". The convention, however, is to always begin your variable names with a letter, not "$" or "*". Additionally, the dollar sign character, by convention, is never used at all.

If it is not working, compile the file with the `-encoding` option (normally without `-encoding`, it should work. This is not a necessary step first check without this).

> **-encoding:** encoding

Set the source file encoding name, such as EUC-JP and UTF-8... If `-encoding` is not specified, the platform default converter is used.

```
javac -encoding UTF-8 HelloWorld.java
```

### How to configure your IDE:

I am using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA):

Add an additional command line parameter: `-encoding UTF-8`

[image]

It's worked!

[image]

Comment: How would I do it? I get an error even while putting a $ infront of the variable name.

Comment: just declare variable name with Unicode char and  printed no need of additional libraries or any thing

Comment: This is what I get when I do an example almost the same as yours.

http://gyazo.com/2b85303eb26dc94853f7c4ea53a5cc27

Comment: If I replace the variable name with regular text, it works perfectly fine.  It's a very odd error.

Comment: Checked and it's basically the same.

Comment: Specifying `-encoding UTF-8` to the compiler makes only sense if the files are actually encoded using `UTF-8`. When using an IDE, the IDE will know whether the files are `UTF-8` encoded as otherwise the editor would mess up the contents. In other words, if the default encoding is already `UTF-8`, you don’t need to specify `-encoding UTF-8`, if it isn’t, specifying it will break the compile process. If you want to use `UTF-8`, you have to look for the IDEs option for encoding of the files in the first place. The IDE should know how to pass that information to the compiler then…

Comment: @holger by default my ide also work like that without adding -encoding UTF-8 it's worked but the problem is Matt's ide configuration goes wrong or something very odd behavior that's why I gave this. but there may be good solution out there.  "If It is Not Working" I try to say by default It should be work without adding -encoding

Answer (score 2):

It is a legal name. From [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) 3.8 Identifiers - Letters and digits (for identifiers) may be drawn from the entire Unicode character set, which supports most writing scripts in use in the world today, including the large sets for Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. This allows programmers to use identifiers in their programs that are written in their native languages.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Unicode itself (not only a character) as a variable, like the below mentioned screenshot.

[image]

1. As you can see, the Sysout with \u0020 (space character) there isn't any error.
2. In the below we are creating a string variable (P) with Unicode, and it can even print "Hi" in the console if you run the program by removing last Sysout.
3. When trying to print a Unicode character (Q -- \u0051) which is not defined, giving a compilation error.

It looks weird, but Java supports it, as [mentioned by Evgeniy Dorofeev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453894/can-i-use-unicode-as-java-variables/29453983#29453983).

Comment: "As you can see, the Sysout with \u0020 (space character) there isn't any error." And it is identical to writing `System.out.println(    )`.  No spaces are printed.