# Creating a new structure with the _family object in FHIR

Tags: java, json, hl7-fhir

How can I get this structure about [FHIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Healthcare_Interoperability_Resources) in Java?

```
{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "name": [
    {
      "family": "Family1-Family2",
      "_family": {
        "extension": [
          {
            "url": "http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/humanname-mothers-family",
            "valueString": "Family2"
          }
        ]
      }
      "given": ["Names"],
    }
  ]
}
```

I try with

```
HumanName name = HumanName();
name.setFamilyElement(_family).addExtension(ext);
```

But this instruction renames my object *name.Family* to _family and does not generate an `Extensión` into _family.

I tried with

```
HumanName name = HumanName();
Extensión ext = new Extensión() ......
......
name.setFamilyElement(_family).addExtension(ext);
```

But this instruction renames my object *name.Family* to _family and not generate `Extensión` into _family.

I try with `name.addChild(_family)`, but it doesn’t work.

Some idea?

Comment: Very slightly related: *[Java Unicode encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533097/java-unicode-encoding)*, *[How to compile Java code using Unicode characters in identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73281146/how-compile-java-using-unicode-characters-in-identifiers)*, and *[Can I use Unicode as Java variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29453894/using-unicode-as-java-variables)*.

Answer (score 0):

In the Java, you don't need to differentiate 'family' and '_family' - those are artifacts of the JSON representation (they don't show up that way in XML or RDF).  In the Java objects, there's just 'family'.  The _family bit will manifest automatically when you serialize as JSON.